# Python: Mapping between two arrays with an index array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
src = np.random.rand(320,240)
```

and another numpy array `idx` of size (2 x (320*240)). Each column of `idx` indexes an entry in a result array `dst`, e.g., `idx[:,20] = [3,10]` references row 3, column 10 in `dst` and the assumption is that `20` corresponds to the flattened index of `src`, i.e., `idx` establishes a mapping between the entries of `src` and `dst`. Assuming `dst` is initialized with all zeros, how can I copy the entries in `src` to their destination in `dst` without a loop?

Comment: What is `res` ?

Comment: Sorry, typo, `res` should be `dst`. Question updated.

Comment: A recent similar question: [Reoder the columns of each row of a numpy array based on another numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112085/reoder-the-columns-of-each-row-of-a-numpy-array-based-on-another-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the canonical way of doing it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> src = np.random.rand(4, 3)
>>> src
array([[0.0309325 , 0.72261479, 0.98373595],
       [0.06357406, 0.44763809, 0.45116039],
       [0.63992938, 0.6445605 , 0.01267776],
       [0.76084312, 0.61888759, 0.2138713 ]])
>>> 
>>> idx = np.indices(src.shape).reshape(2, -1)
>>> np.random.shuffle(idx.T)
>>> idx
array([[3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> 
>>> dst = np.empty_like(src)
>>> dst[tuple(idx)] = src.ravel()
>>> dst
array([[0.2138713 , 0.44763809, 0.98373595],
       [0.06357406, 0.63992938, 0.6445605 ],
       [0.61888759, 0.76084312, 0.01267776],
       [0.45116039, 0.0309325 , 0.72261479]])
```

If you can't be sure that `idx` is a proper shuffle it's a bit safer to use `np.full` with a fill value that does not appear in `src` instead of `np.empty`.

```
>>> dst = np.full_like(src, np.nan)
>>> dst[tuple(idx)] = src.ravel()
>>> 
>>> dst
array([[0.27020869, 0.71216066,        nan],
       [0.63812283, 0.69151451, 0.65843901],
       [       nan, 0.02406174, 0.47543061],
       [0.05650845,        nan,        nan]])
```

If you spot the fill value in `dst`, something is wrong with `idx`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Actually, it is quite possible in my case that indices may appear multiple times in idx (and others do not at all). In your version, the number appearing in dst would be the one corresponding to the last appearance of the index in idx, right? Is it possible to control this behavior based on a precedence array p, i.e., if an index appears twice copy the entry whose precedence in p is higher?

(if you are curious, this is for multi-view geometry in a renderer)

Comment: [Officially](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), _For advanced assignments, there is in general no guarantee for the iteration order. This means that if an element is set more than once, it is not possible to predict the final result._ I'm not aware of a quick fix for the precedence. Why don't you make a new question, I think it is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
dst[idx[0, :], idx[1, :]] = src.flat

In [33]: src = np.random.randn(2, 3)

In [34]: src
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0.68636938,  0.60275041,  1.26078727],
       [ 1.17937849, -1.0369404 ,  0.42847611]])

In [35]: dst = np.zeros_like(src)

In [37]: idx = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]])

In [38]: dst[idx[0, :], idx[1, :]] = src.flat

In [39]: dst
Out[39]: 
array([[ 0.42847611,  0.68636938, -1.0369404 ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.17937849,  0.60275041]])
```

dst[0, 1] is src[0, 0], etc.